# Problem with connecting pins on an Arduino board with an L239D shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, arduino-motor-shield

I have an L239D motor shield just like the Adafruit motor shield. I had a question in my mind. While making a robot, I could not connect my pins from various sensors in Arduino as the motor shield is already fitted on the board. So how can I connect my pins?

PS: I have the same board as shown in the picture [image]

Comment: With solder and wire to the pins that aren't used by the motor shield? To a prototyping shield between the Arduino and the motor shield? To another Arduino and link the two together through some serial protocol or other? There's millions of ways. You don't have to limit yourself to just sticking bits of LEGO® together. Get creative.

Comment: You could use the 6 analog pins, as those are accessible in the bottom-right corner (you can use analog pins just like a digital pin). Second option if to remove the headers from the shield, and replace them with [stacking headers](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10007)

Answer (score 1):

That's a common problem that has many solutions.

The cheapest way is to solder the wires directly as many comments said. Though this is quite dirty, it should work for you.

The more professional way is to use these [Arduino stackable header](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10007). They can even let you have a shield on top of your shield. This is the best choice in my opinion.